# Get git branch name in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins (v2.331) with Git Plugin (v4.11).
I found that Jenkins allowes regular expressions or ${ENV_VARIABLE} as a branch-specifier at the "Branches to build" option. My problem is:
Can I use both regular expression and ${ENV_VARIABLE} to specify the branches?
such as: `:.*/${version}/\d{8}` . I also tried to use  wildcards:`*/${version}/*`.But it doesn't seem to get the correct result.

Comment: "can I use..." In what context? In a script, I assume? WIll you give some more details please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.